# Backbone View render function getting called multiple times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a view that represents a folder. I have bunch of subviews, that this folder view creates, each representing a unique thumbnail in that folder. It turns out that each one of those subview's render method is getting called multiple times (3). Is there a way to find out how view's render method is called. There are different places which could render a trigger event for e.g., if models metadata is changed. It has become a huge mess and I'm looking for a way to debug backbone view's to know what is exactly triggering render method.

Comment: You could override the `trigger` method to track what events are triggered.

Comment: can you please provide give me some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I always debug events is:

```
view.on('all', function(eventName){
    console.log('Name of View: ' + eventName);
});
```

You could do this on views, models or collections.

**example**:
http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/phw4t/6/

I added the `request` and `sync` methods manually to simulate how backbone would actually perform. The `rendered` event is custom -- nothing listens to it. Just to show you how/when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

So as you requested, here's an example of how to override the `trigger` method. Note that you'll have to override it for all types of classes (Model, View, Collection, Router).

```
var trigger = Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger;
Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger = Backbone.View.prototype.trigger = Backbone.Collection.prototype.trigger = Backbone.Router.prototype.trigger = function(name) {
  trigger.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log(this, 'triggered the event', name, '.').
}
```

You could be more specific by overriding each method individually to add the type of object in the log. But you got the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You might what to give [`backbone.debug`](http://andrewterris.com/backbone.debug/) a try. Should give you some insight into what events are being fired.